# Is there a way to create a geom_path heatmap in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, heatmap

For example, this is a heatmap from a website using GPS data:

[image]

I have gotten some degree of success with adding a `weight` parameter to each vertex and calculating the number of events that have vertices near those, but that takes a long time, especially with a large amount of data. It also appears a bit spotty when the distance between vertices is a bit wonky, which causes random splotches of different colors throughout the heatmap. It looks kind of cool, but it makes the data a bit harder to read.

When you zoom out, it looks a bit more continuous due to the paths overlapping more.

[image]

In R, the closest I can do to this involves using an alpha channel, but that only gets me a monochromatic heatmap, which is not always desirable, especially when you want to see lesser-traveled paths visibly. In theory I could do two lines to resolve the visibility part (first opaque, second semi-transparent), but I would like to be able to have different hue values.

Ideally I would like this to work with ggplot, but if it cannot, I would accept other methods, provided they are reasonably quick computationally.

Edit: The data format is a data frame with sequential (latitude,  longitude) coordinate pairs, along with some associated data that can be used for filter & grouping (such as activity type and event ID).

Here is a sample of the data for the region displayed in the above images (~1.5 MB):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/13p2jtz4760m26d/sample_coordinate_data.csv?dl=0

Comment: not knowing the data format is problematic for folks who likely could assist

Comment: well, mapping the same data twice, each time with a different color and with transparency inverted the second time, you get a bichromatic plot instead of a monochromatic. could be a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
ggplot() + geom_count(data, aes(longitude, latitude, alpha=..prop..))
```

but you need to show some data to check how it works.

Comment: The data I have isn't binned. It's relatively continuous, and the separation between the points is significant depending on how closely you zoom in.  I am looking for a generalized gradient, not just an alpha-based one. E.g., the example I gave above is purple for lesser-traveled paths, becomes more orange, and then more yellow for more-traversed paths. The only method I can think of atm would involve emulating drawing the lines on a large matriix, incrementing each point, and putting a geom_raster() over ggplot after using `reshape2()'`s `melt()` or something like that.

Comment: So try to use geom_count(aes(... color=..prop..)) + scale_color_gradient(low="orange", high="yellow")

Comment: So I did that with a single event that involved overlapping segments 10-20 times in one part. The end result was a mixture of the highest and lowest end of the scale. Even some of the single-track areas with no technical overlap were considered overlapped. While this is definitely on the right track, I would need to refine this more.  Image example: https://i.imgur.com/PEhzfmp.png

Comment: Also, I needed to adjust the `size` argument of `aes()`, since the size is scaled by `..prop..` by default in `geom_count()`.

Comment: Each point (each row) is a little different from others. So, I tried to round long and lat, and then plot points:

    `data %>%
      mutate(longitude = round(longitude, 4), latitude = round(latitude, 4)) %>%
      ggplot() +
      geom_count(aes(longitude, latitude, color=..n..), size = 1) +
      scale_color_gradient(low = "purple", high = "yellow") +
    facet_wrap(~filename)`

This is somehow heat map. But I think you want to plot a lot of lines one over another and change color if they crosses? Like shade bobs in old demos (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJtxnQ5_8Zk)?